# Stylized navigation bar with one element aligned with content

Tags: css, layout

I have a unique layout I'm tring to build, but I'm nowhere near experienced enough with css to accomplish it on my own. Maybe someone can help me?

I'd like to have a page which displays content in a centered, vertical box about 700px wide. The content will be individual posts listed vertically (think Tumblr). That's no sweat, but the tough part is the navigation bar.

The bar will contain links to years, with the current year selected in the middle, preceding years to the left, following years to the right, with the whole shebang taking up 100% of the width of the page. The currently selected year I'd like to be as wide as the content column. When the user clicks a different year, that year will display, and the other years will change accordingly (that part I can handle).

Here's an illustration to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Is this something that would be possible? Any ideas on how to accomplish this?
(Ignore the fact that every year on the right is 2010. It should be 2012, 2013, 2014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jQuery Tabs will do the trick: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: It's gonna take a lot of modifying to get the look I want, but this will definitely work.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to cycle the tabs when one is selected, would you? Eg. If I click the 2009 tab, put that tab in the center, delete the last two tabs and add two to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you could build it like a drop down menu with css http://divitodesign.com/css/how-to-dropdown-css-menu/

Or use a php switch statement to set a variable when you click on it. when the page reloads with the variable being pass in the url use it to set a current class to the year you want.